# Cloudsql-proxy error checking scopes and timeout awaiting response headers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy, workload-identity

I have a kubernetes job on GKE that uses cloudsql-proxy as a sidecar. I am using workloadIdentity for the connection:

I have the GSA and KSA setup, and cloudsql-proxy works for the deployment but does not work for the jobs in the same namespaces and using the same serviceaccounts.

I keep getting this error:

```
error checking scopes: *url.Error Get http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/scopes: net/http: timeout awaiting response headers | Get http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/scopes: net/http: timeout awaiting response headers
```

I am not sure what the issue is. I need help.

This is pod container template for cloudsql-proxy:

```
{{ if $global.Values.cloudsql.enabled }}
      - name: cloudsql-proxy
        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.15
        command: [sh, -c]
        args:
          - |
            /cloud_sql_proxy -instances={{ $global.Values.cloudsql.connection_string }}=tcp:{{ $global.Values.cloudsql.port }} -term_timeout=30s -log_debug_stdout=true &
            CHILD_PID=$!
            ls -al
            (while true; do if [[ -f "/signals/finished" ]]; then kill $CHILD_PID; fi; sleep 1; done) &
            wait $CHILD_PID
            if [[ -f "/signals/finished" ]]; then exit 0; fi
        volumeMounts:
          - name: ssl-certs
            mountPath: "/etc/ssl/certs"
          - name: signals
            mountPath: "/signals"
      {{- end }}
```

Comment: What are your scopes in your node pool?

Comment: Try updating gce-proxy to [1.17](http://gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.17) or newer, that should fix it.